# Is it possible to have stacked grouped rows in apex timeline chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

In apex charts library, there is an option to have grouped stacked bars for the regular bar chart. https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/bar-charts/grouped-stacked-bars/.

I want to have this functionality with the range bar chart (https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/timeline-charts/multi-series/), but here the only possible options I see is to have either all of them stacked or have them all in separate rows.

Does anyone have an idea how this can be achieved? Thank you!

I tried adding the group property in the data, but since the format is completely different, it didn't have any effect. Trying to switch the range bar for a regular bar also doesn't seem to work since I need to send an interval for the y data.

I.e. In the picture below, I would want to be able to have 2 rows in 'code', if the data for Joe and Dan are in the same group, to have them stacked.

[Timeline chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twZZD.png)